# change password of user account in java using text files?

Tags: java, file-io, text-files

I have a problem and hope to find a solution.

now i have created a simple program to change password of user account using text files in java.

now i should enter username of the account then change password of that account but there it shows me an error.

here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test6 {
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {

    String newPassword=null;
    boolean checked = true;

 File f= new File("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\accounts.txt");// path to your file
 File tempFile = new File("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\accounts2.txt"); // create a temp file in same path
 BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
 System.out.println("Enter account username you want to edit password?");
 Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
 String username = sc2.next();
 while(sc.hasNextLine())
 {
     String currentLine= sc.nextLine();
     String[] tokens = currentLine.split(" ");
     if(Objects.equals(Integer.valueOf(tokens[0]), username) && checked)
     {
         sc2.nextLine();                          
         System.out.println("New Password:");
         newPassword= sc2.nextLine();
         currentLine = tokens[0]+" "+newPassword;
         checked = false;
     }
     writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));

 }
 writer.close(); 
 sc.close();
 f.delete();
 boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(f);

}
}
```

the error shows to me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "HAMADA"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
at Test6.main(Test6.java:25)
```

the format of my text file is like that:

```
HAMADA 115599
JOHNY 4477100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `Integer.valueOf(tokens[0])` on line 25 to just `tokens[0]`.

In your code, you try to get the integer value of the username, when you should be getting its `String` representation. You do not need the `Integer.valueOf()`. (The error is thrown because you are trying to get the `Integer` representation of a non-integer type.)

On a side note, you should never have password-storing text files, especially when the passwords and the files are both unencrypted. Use a database instead.

Comment: @BeginnerProgrammer No problem. I'm glad it helped!